# XPATH: Select a node whose children do not containg some text

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select a node whose children do not contain some specific text.
For example:

```
<div class="b-margin">
    <div class="tag">Pt</div>
    <div class="tag">En</div>
</div>
<div class="b-margin">
    <div class="tag">Ru</div>
    <div class="tag">En</div>
</div>
```

How would i go about selecting the 'div class="b-margin"' nodes that do not have children with the text "Pt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple xpath.

```
//div[@class='b-margin' and not(div[.='Pt'])]
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Plus one but note that `[not(div[.='Pt'])]` can be more simply written as `[not(div='Pt')]`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, but I have no idea why. When I test it on the webpage I'm working on firefox, it matches all the b-margin nodes.

Comment: is it possible to share the page?